# How to unmount unionfs-fuse filesystem

Tags: unionfs

I have mounted a directory with the following command

```
sudo unionfs -o cow,max_files=32768 -o allow_other,use_ino,suid,dev,nonempty stuff-linux64=RW stuff
```

How do I change stuff-linux64 from RW to RO and add another directory (stuff-update64) on top?

The end result should look like I'd executed:

```
sudo unionfs -o cow,max_files=32768 -o allow_other,use_ino,suid,dev,nonempty stuff-update64=RW:stuff-linux64=RO stuff
```

after unmounting stuff.

For that matter, how do I unmount a filesystem that I mounted with unionfs?

Answer (score 4):

`unionfs` is a shorthand for `unionfs-fuse` which is built atop the FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) system.  Therefore, the preferable way to unmount a unionfs-fuse is through the FUSE system directly using `fusermount -u ~/example-mount-point` (the `-u` switch means "unmount").

A big advantage of using `fusermount` instead of `umount` is it requires no privilege elevation. As the name implies, FUSE all happens in userspace. That means both mounting and unmounting can be accomplished from your limited user account, with no need for `sudo`, provided of course that you have permission to access the directories you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

I think just `umount <the-mount-dir>` is enough.

Here is an example:
Say I have this directory structure under `/tmp/unionfs`:

```
.
├── Fruits
│   ├── Apple
│   └── Tomato
└── Vegetables
    ├── celery
    └── Tomato

2 directories, 4 files
```

Now mount the `Fruits` and `Vegetables` on `/tmp/mnt`:

```
$ unionfs-fuse /tmp/unionfs/Fruits:/tmp/unionfs/Vegetables /tmp/mnt
```

To unmount it do this:

```
# umount /tmp/mnt
```

Comment: Got that - thanks - at least this gives me a work-around (unmount/remount)